# Формула массива SumProduct (суммпроизв) через vba

Tags: excel, vba

Не получается никак через vba ввести формулу массива (вылетает ошибка), делаю так:

```
Set rangeDir = Workbooks(fExp).Sheets(fExpShN).Range(Workbooks(fExp).Sheets(fExpShN).Cells(4, 1).Address, Workbooks(fExp).Sheets(fExpShN).Cells(rowsCountFileExp, 1).Address)

Set rangeSumS = Workbooks(fExp).Sheets(fExpShN).Range(Workbooks(fExp).Sheets(fExpShN).Cells(4, 5).Address, Workbooks(fExp).Sheets(fExpShN).Cells(rowsCountFileExp, columnsCountFileExp).Address)

direct = "Условие 1"

Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct((direct = rangeDir) * (rangeSumS))
```

В экселе ввожу и все работает, никаких проблем

Comment: Ваш код о хотелка не стыкуются. Что же все таки надо, ввести формулу массива в ячейку или же лишь воспользоваться ей в VBA? Про использование ответ дан. Если же нужно ввести ее в ячейку, то для этого имеется FormulaArray. 
Range("A25").FormulaArray = "=SUM(IF(A1:A14>10,A1:A14,1))"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В формулах листа оператор "=" умеет работать с массивом, но в VBA так не получится.

Можно вычислять как формулу листа:

```
Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("SumProduct((""Условие 1"" = A4:A10) * E4:H10)")
```

Но зачем функция листа, если VBA сам может справиться?

```
Sub uuu()
Dim ArrDir(), ArrSumS()
Dim direct As String
Dim dSum As Double
Dim i As Long, j As Long
    i = 10: j = 8 ' где-то раньше определили последние строку/столбец
    direct = "Условие 1" ' значение для сравнения

    ' значения диапазонов листа записываем в массивы
    With Workbooks(fExp).Sheets(fExpShN)
        ArrDir = .Range("A4:A" & i).Value
        ArrSumS = .Range(.Cells(4, 5), .Cells(i, j)).Value
    End With

    ' переменные i, j уже свободны, используем в циклах
    For i = 1 To UBound(ArrDir) ' цикл по вертикали
        If ArrDir(i, 1) = direct Then
            For j = 1 To UBound(ArrSumS, 2) ' цикл по второй размерности
                dSum = dSum + ArrSumS(i, j) ' сумма
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

    Debug.Print dSum
End Sub

 --------------------------------
```

Примечания к коду автора:

- родителя можно определять один раз: оператор *With/End Wiht* ускоряет обработку  и помогает сделать код читабельнее;
- ссылка на книгу не нужна, если макрос записан в этой же книге;
- для определения диапазона не обязательно применять .Address;
- строка *Application.WorksheetFunction...* в любом случае вызвала бы ошибку: получаемое значение никуда не передается.

Правильно:

*.Cells(1,1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction...*

*dSum = Application.WorksheetFunction...*

*MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction...*